# Автоматический запуск видео. Можно ли усовершенствовать ссылку?

Tags: ссылки

Есть ссылка на видео, которое лежит на гугл-диске. Допустим такая: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Qnp0lxJIX4S8PU7rxf7sjjs118C4P1aY.
Если пройти по ссылке, то откроется страница с этим видео. Но для просмотра необходимо нажать "пуск".

Мне же нужно чтобы видео запускалось автоматически.

Вопрос в следующем: Можно ли **добавить какую-то команду в тело ссылки**, которая самостоятельно запустить это видео?

Comment: Вам нужно встроить видео на сайт фреймом или чтоб переходило прямо на сайт и там воспроизводилось видео?

Comment: Виталий, мне нужно, что бы видео автоматически воспроизводилось прямо на сайте гугла. Ссылка будет вызываться из андроид-приложения. Нажимаем кнопочку, открывается браузер, затем страница с видео и автоматический его запуск. Вот так мне бы очень хотелось сделать.

Comment: Вот это, думаю, вряд ли получится

Comment: Вы разбили мне сердце( Придется объяснять ребенку, что нажимать нужно дважды)